# Whatsapp: Do NOT keep images for certain groups / contacts

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, images, contact-groups

Is there any way in Whatsapp on Android to exclude saving pictures of certain groups / contacts into the "Whatsapp Images" folder?

I know I could delete them manually by going into the Group -> "Media" and select all images manually, but rather I'd love to have the opposite behaviour so that I need to specify which images I want to keep / save.

This is also the way it works on iOS: You can specify for every group / contact separately whether images/videos should be kept or not...

Is there any way of asking for this feature officially on whatsapp?
Thanks